# Using floor to get whole number from double

Tags: c++

If `x` and `y` are `double`, why can I not do:

`int nx = floor(x)` or `int ny = floor(y)` to round down to a whole number which would work with `int`?

Comment: Are you sure the rounded values of `x` and `y` can be stored in an `int`? `double` can represent values that `int` can't.

Comment: What tells you that you can't use floor() in this way?

Comment: What happens when you try to do what you are doing?

Comment: if that's what you need you should do: `int nx = (int)floor(x)`

Comment: @PaulFloyd MSVS compile-time says `double to int possible loss of data`.

Comment: You need to `static_cast<int>(floor(x))` because the result might still overflow an `int` and you need to tell the compiler that you are willing to accept overflow. Consider the case where you have `float x = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() + 1;`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes. I need to see whole number values to see if a match occurs between `floor(y) == y` to determine if I am in a new square on a grid or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even when we consider only integers, `float` can store values that `int` cannot.  For example, consider this case:

```
float x = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() + 1f;

// Even floored, the value is out of range!
int y = floor(x);
```

There are even some other, special values like positive infinity, negative infinity, and NaN, which an `int` variable cannot hold.  (There's also negative zero, but that's defined in the standard to be equal to positive zero, so it manages to squeak through.)

Because of this, this conversion is considered "narrowing" and you <s>must</s> should explicitly perform it with a cast (so that both the compiler and the future maintainers of your program know that it was not a mistake):

```
int y = static_cast<int>(floor(x));
```

"Narrowing conversion" simply means that the domain of the destination type is not a subset of the domain of the source type, so there are some inputs that cannot accurately be represented in the destination type.  The explicit cast is your way of telling the compiler that you are willing to accept the consequences if a conversion is performed where the value cannot be represented in the destination type.

---

Also note that the default behavior when casting from a floating-point type to an integer type is to truncate the fractional component, so the `floor()` call is redundant.  You can just do:

```
int y = static_cast<int>(x);
```

Comment: Unless the rules changed drastically (which would break billions of lines of code), there is no explicit cast required here. The special rules for narrowing conversions apply to "list initializations", i.e., `int y = { x };`. `int y = x;` has been legal (assuming the value is in range) since time immemorial.

Answer (score 1):

you have to cast the result to int so you can store it into one...

```
int nx = (int)(floor(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to know about the domain of your values. If, as you say in the comments, you are using the double overload (see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) for full details) then there is indeed a possible loss of data.

double can represent numbers up to about 1e308 though above about 1e17 there is no fractional part. int can only manage about 2e9. So if you know that your domain will never exceed 2 billion, then it should be safe to use and you can either ignore the warning or use a cast to make it go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = 1.5;
int i = d;
```

The second intialization truncates the floating-point value and stores the result into `i`. The result here is valid and well-defined: `i` gets the value 1. (If the resulting value could not be represented in an `int` the behavior would be undefined; that's not the case here).

The warning is telling you that the conversion loses information. That's correct, because values like 1.4 and 1.5 will both be converted to 1, so you would no longer be able to tell the difference. The new terminology for that is a "narrowing conversion". But despite the warning, the conversion is legal. There is no need for a cast here, except perhaps to quiet over-zealous compilers. Unless, of course, you have your compiler set to turn warnings into errors, in which case you'll spend a fair amount of time sorting out how to persuade your compiler to compile valid and meaningful code that some compiler-writer thinks deserves a warning.